ERROR: Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
I installed android studio in my new pc and now when i tried to run a sample flutter project it gives this gradle and java error:

I tried to run the code on the virtual device as well as on the physical device using USB debugging and still the problem persists.
here is the main file i tried to execute:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}


My android studio is installed in Drive(F) and flutter and gradle are installed in drive(C).

Please try again with stable network connection or different connection, make sure you're not using private network
Can you please provide your flutter doctor -v your flutter run --verbose

i executed those commands on CMD and these r the results:


flutter doctor -v: only chrome and visual studio were not installed everything else was green tick.


flutter run --verbose: Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
[   +2 ms]
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      FlutterCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1831:9)


